# While parsing .ods file with pandas using read_excel() (and odf), how to drop comments in cells?

Tags: python, pandas, ods, odf

I'm trying to parse `.ods` files with pandas, using `pd.read_excel()` function, which uses `odf` under the hood. The problem I face is simple: some cells have comments, and pandas treat them as if they were some regular content.

Here is a basic example ; given a very simple .ods file with a single comment:

[image]

Importing that file into a dataframe using

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel("example_with_comment.ods")
```

gives:

[image]

while I would have liked to retrieve the content of the cell only.
Does anyone know how to drop the comments during parsing ?

I'm using pandas 1.3.4.

Thanks a lot to anyone who could give me a hint !

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bug. You may try, instead of read_excel, to use this module:

https://pypi.org/project/pandas-ods-reader/

Comment: That solves the bug indeed. However, I cannot use some useful options from pandas.read_csv(), such as `skip_rows=` for instance; plus it adds a dependency. Well, if it can't be helped ?

Comment: It also loses a lot of features, like the automatic conversion from empty values to np.nan :/